# How can I get a PHP function that handles an AJAX function to return a boolean?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I've been testing and found out that if

```
session_start();
if ( $_POST['animal'] != $_SESSION['animal'] ) die(json_encode(false));
```

is run inside my PHP function to handle the AJAX call, then back in JavaScript land where I have

```
        success: function (correctCaptcha) {
            console.log("correctCaptcha is " + correctCaptcha); // test
            console.log("correctCaptcha's type is " + typeof (correctCaptcha)); // test
                if ( correctCaptcha )
                {
```

I'm seeing that `correctCaptcha` is the string "false" rather than the boolean value `false`. Consequently, the `if` block is entered and that's what's causing a bug. How can I get PHP to give me a boolean as the JSON it generates? Or what is a better solution?

Comment: Simple solution would be `if ( correctCaptcha == "false")`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Obviously, but I don't want to jerry-rig the coding of this site too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
json_encode((bool)1); // which is true
```

Or

```
json_encode((bool)0); // which is false
```

Ideally though you would want to do something like this

```
$results = ["result" => false];
json_encode($results);
```

From the documents, this should retain the boolean, not convert to a string.

Then access the results in your javascript like this (as an object)

```
console.log(correctCaptcha.result);
```